# GIT - How to list modified files (filename.ext) from a date filtering by file type

Tags: php, git

I'm trying to get all modified files from a date filtered by a file extension and saving this result into a file. For instance todeploy.txt.  Im working on windows git client.

My command should be like this:  ***Give me all distinct modified files which extension is in .php,.inc,.js,.html and were not deleted and belongs to a specific folder.***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using the command `find` .  `man find` from the command line to get some help

Comment: @edi9999 Hello! and thnx. Please, can you give me an example?.

Answer (score 0):

I would use git diff to show modofied files like that `git diff --name-only "@{1 day ago}" *.php *.inc`. Did it work for you?

Comment: Hello and thanks @grimsock. I have tried your solution but it didn't work. I got this message: **fatal: ambiguous argument '*.php': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'**

Comment: So did you try version with double dash as in error message was written? Like this? `git diff --name-only "@{1 day ago}" -- *.php *.inc`